# Traget Group draining with 503 error and Unable to access port 3001 through domain name in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, mern, amazon-elb

I am new to AWS and I was trying to host a complete MERN application on EC2 using ECS and Docker. In my project, I have separate frontend and backend modules. In ECS, I have created 2 tasks(EC2), 1 each for frontend and backend. In frontend, I have added a container, which has port mapping to host mapping of `80 to 80`. Also, added some environment variables. For backend, I have added 2 containers with port mappings to host mappings of `3001 to 3001` and `27017 to 27017`. I have also added links and hostname.
I have assigned 512 Task memory (MiB) and 512 CPU unit for frontend task and for backend task, these values are 128 MiB and 128 unit.
Then, I created 2 load balancers and 2 target groups, with frontend LB have a listener on port 80 and 443 and backend LB have listeners on 3001 and 443.
The frontend's target group has a protocol:port of http:80, while the backend one has of http:3001.
I have also created 2 separate routes and linked to each of 2 LB. I then created 2 services with respective tasks and LBs. The issue I am having right now is with backend service. The frontend works fine. I am able to access through public IP as well as domain name(Route 53), but the backend only works with public IP. So, basically, http://x.x.x.x:3001/api works, but https://domain.name/api does not work. It shows `503 Temporary Service unavailable`.

I did try to find the issue and the Target Group(backend) is trying to register the instance on port 3001, but, it keeps on failing. Also surprisongly, When the target registration starts & is in `initial` stage, the domain name works too, but, then it goes to `unhealthy(Failed due to 404)` stage, then domain shows me `502 bad gateway` error. And then, target starts `draining`, after which it shows `503 Temporary Service unavailable`.
I have also opened all ports 80, 3001, 22, 443 in the security group.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening? Is this even possible? Do I need to post more details?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Sadly your question lacks details. What network mode you use on ecs? What are SGs on LB and the ec2 instances? What are target groups settings exactly? health checks?

Comment: Not an answer to your question but, if you are new to AWS and ECS I would strongly suggest to use [AWS Copilot](https://aws.github.io/copilot-cli) to construct your two services. It hides a lot of the ECS complexity (or richness?) you are dealing with by creating all the mechanics for you in the backend. In this case you want to have a ["LB service" + a "backend service" in the same Copilot application](https://aws.github.io/copilot-cli/docs/concepts/services/).

Comment: @Marcin I don't quite get your question, but, I have mainy used all the default settings. I used the default VPC in EC2 instance of cluster, along with default availability zones/subnets. I have a security group with the required ports opened that I am also using on LBs. Target Group port is 3001. Health Check path is `/`, port is `Traffic Port`, Timeout is `5 seconds` and TG has same VPC as before.

Comment: @mreferre Thanks, I will look into this too, but, it would be great if I grasp the concepts completely.

Comment: "I have also opened all ports 80, 3001, 22, 443 in the security group." this is SG for what? Load balancer, EC2? Also what network mode are you using, bridge, host, avsvpc? What are  https listeners that you use? Your question lacks details and necessary information to even try to help you.

Comment: @Marcin That SG is for ECS cluster,so, it's the one that both EC2 and LB are using. Network mode is `default`, which is Bridge on Linux and NAT on Windows.

Comment: Fair enough (and I love/support the spirit). Many customers see Copilot as a boost-starter they can use to learn about the "how" (easy to walk backwards from it and see what it has done in your account for learning purposes - if need be).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so, I was able to solve this problem. Did some digging and turns out, everyone was talking about Target Group's health checks urls, so, I changed the health check url from `/` to `/backendhealth`. Then, in Advanced Health Settings, I also changed the port setting from `Traffic Port` to `Override` to `80` port and it successfully registered the respective cluster's EC2 Instance on port 3001.
So relieved!!!